# Q: How to add ghosts in Pacman in Pygames

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, pygame, pacman

I'm making a Pacman-like game in Pygames. Instead of pac-dots it's mushrooms. The code works fine, the only problem is I have no idea how to implement the 'ghosts'. I am very new to programming, so keep it simple. Thanks!

My code so far (everything works, just not ghosts):

```
import pygame

# Define some colors
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN    = (   0, 255,   0)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)
PATHS    = (204 ,155 , 120)
GRASSWALL= (69  , 201,  54)
Stone    = (204 , 204, 204)

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (800, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Darudernauts")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.load('darude.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(pygame.constants.USEREVENT)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

player_image = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Mark\Documents\player.gif").convert()
shroom_image = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Mark\Documents\shroom.gif").convert()

# Hide the mouse cursor
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
# Speed in pixels per frame
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
x = 350
y = 200

shroom_list_x = [150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,150,600,600,600,600,600,600,600,600,600,600,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,  0, 50,100,650,700,750,  0, 50,100,650,700,750,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,300,350,400,450,250,250,250,250,250,250,500,500,500,500,500,500,350,400,350,400,400,-50]
shroom_list_y = [  0, 50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,  0, 50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,100,100,100,100,100,100,350,350,350,350,350,350,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,300,300,300,300,100,150,200,250,300,350,100,150,200,250,300,350,100,100,150,150,200,-50]

score = 0
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    move_horizontally = 0
    move_vertically = 0

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        # Figure out if it was an arrow key. If so
        # adjust speed.
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            move_horizontally = -50
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            move_horizontally = 50
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            move_vertically = -50
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            move_vertically = 50
    # --- Game logic should go here
    #side tps
    if x < -50:
        x = 750
    if x > 800:
        x = -50
    #top/bot tps
    if y < -50:
        y = 450
    if y > 500:
        y = -50

    #midtop
    if x == 150 and y == 0:
        move_horizontally = 0#left

    if x == 600 and y == 0:
        move_horizontally = 0#right

    if x == 150 and y == 450:
        move_horizontally = 0#left

    if x == 600 and y == 450:
        move_horizontally = 0#right

    if x == 150 and y == 50:
        if move_horizontally < 0:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if x == 600 and y == 50:
        if move_horizontally > 0:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if x == 600 and y == 400:
        if move_horizontally > 0:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if x >= 200 and x <= 550 and y == 50:
        if move_vertically < 0:
            move_vertically = 0


    if x == 200 or x == 300 or x == 450 or x == 550:
        if y == 50:
            move_vertically = 0

    if x == 150:
        if y >= 0 and y <= 450:
            if y != 100 and y != 350:
                if move_horizontally < 0:
                    move_horizontally =0

    if x == 200 and y == 400:
        move_vertically = 0

    if x == 550 and y == 400:
        move_vertically = 0

    if x == 300 or x == 350 or x == 400 or x == 450:
        if y == 400:
            move_vertically = 0


    #topleft path
    if x >= 0 and x <= 100 and y == 100:
        move_vertically = 0
    #botright path
    if x >= 0 and x <= 100 and y == 350:
        move_vertically = 0
    #topright path
    if x >= 650 and x <= 800 and y == 100:
        move_vertically = 0
    #botright path
    if x >= 650 and x <= 800 and y == 350:
        move_vertically = 0

    if x == 150:
        if y == 150 or y == 200 or y == 250 or y == 300:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if x == 600:
        if y == 150 or y == 200 or y == 250 or y == 300:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if y == 100 and x == 150:
        if move_horizontally >= 0:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if y == 350 and x == 150:
        if move_horizontally >= 0:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if y == 100 and x == 600:
        if move_horizontally <= 0:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if y == 350 and x == 600:
        if move_horizontally <= 0:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if x == 250 and y == 400:
        if move_vertically > 0:
            move_vertically = 0

    if x == 500 and y == 400:
        if move_vertically > 0:
            move_vertically = 0

    if x == 250 and y == 350:
        move_horizontally = 0

    if x == 500 and y == 350:
        move_horizontally = 0

    if x < 0 or x > 800:
        move_vertically = 0

    if y < 0 or y == 500:
        move_horizontally = 0

    if y == 300:
        if x == 300 or x == 350 or x == 400 or x == 450:
            move_vertically = 0

    if y == 300 and x == 250:
        if move_horizontally < 0:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if y == 300 and x == 500:
        if move_horizontally > 0:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if x == 250 or x == 500:
        if y == 100 or y == 150 or y == 200 or y == 250:
            move_horizontally = 0

    if x == 350:
        if y == 100 or y == 150:
            if move_horizontally < 0:
                move_horizontally = 0

    if x == 400:
        if y == 100 or y == 150:
            if move_horizontally > 0:
                move_horizontally = 0

    if x == 350 and y == 200:
        if move_horizontally < 0:
            move_horizontally = 0
        elif move_vertically > 0:
            move_vertically = 0

    if x == 400 and y == 200:
        if move_horizontally > 0:
            move_horizontally = 0
        elif move_vertically > 0:
            move_vertically = 0

    x = x + move_horizontally
    y = y + move_vertically


    if score == 69:
        print "VICTORY!!! YOU'VE COLLECTED 69 MUSHROOMS!!!"

    # --- Drawing code should go here

    # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(Stone)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[0,0,150,100])#TOPLEFT
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[0,150,150,200])#MIDLEFT
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[0,400,150,100])#BOTLEFT

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[650,0,150,100])#TOPRIGHT
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[650,150,150,200])#MIDRIGHT
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[650,400,150,100])#BOTRIGHT

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[200,0,400,50])#MIDTOP
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[200,450,400,50])#MIDBOT

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[200,100,50,300])#JUNGLEFT
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[550,100,50,300])#JUNGRIGHT
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[300,350,200,50])#JUNGBOT

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[300,250,200,50])#BASEBOT
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[300,100,50,150])#BASELEFT
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GRASSWALL,[450,100,50,150])#BASERIGHT

    player_image = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Mark\Documents\player.gif").convert()
    shroom_image = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Mark\Documents\shroom.gif").convert()
    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
        # Get the current mouse position. This returns the position
    # as a list of two numbers.

    x += x_speed
    y += y_speed

##    print x
##    print y

    # Copy image to screen:
    screen.blit(player_image, [x, y])

    for shrm in range(0, len(shroom_list_x)-1):
        if x == shroom_list_x[shrm] and y == shroom_list_y[shrm]:
            shroom_list_x.pop(shrm)
            shroom_list_y.pop(shrm)
            score += 1
            print "SCORE:",score,"mushrooms"

        screen.blit(shroom_image, [shroom_list_x[shrm], shroom_list_y[shrm]])
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 7 frames per second
    clock.tick(10)

# Close the window and quit.
# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
# on exit if running from IDLE.
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know what the pieces of implementing enemies involves? At the least it will require some rudimentary AI (even if that AI is only `go right until wall then turn left`). Your question is quite broad and not likely to get many, if any, answers without being narrowed down.

Comment: Like I said, I'm very new to Python and programming in general. I don't have any experience with A.I.s so forgive, I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does seem to be geared more towards the Game Development site [https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/], but I'll give you some advice. For a very simple enemy, you'd be best off creating the "ghosts" as objects that cause a game over if they collide with the player object. As for AI, you could start with something simple such as assigning the "ghost" a direction to follow until it collides with a wall, then call a random integer to determine its new direction. Simple and to the point. Like I said earlier however, you'll want to ask the folks over at Game Developement or somewhere else for better answers. Also, this site handles programming errors and bugs rather than concepts. Good luck!